# wx.BoxSizer items not aligning correctly

Tags: python, wxpython

I am using wx.BoxSizers to align the elements of my (here simplified) program.  I need blue panel1 to be shaped at a 4:3 aspect ratio, but expanded to fill the frame, and to do so I give it proportion=1.  However I want the text to sit directly beneath panel1, but as small as possible (porportion=0)

When I set this up, however, panel1 expands downward (even though it is shaped, supposedly), and the text is pushed to the bottom of the window.  I want the text to 'hug' panel1 even as the window is resized. How do I fix this? Thanks!

```
import wx

class myWindow(wx.Window):
    def __init__(self, parent, size):
        wx.Window.__init__(self, parent=parent, size=size)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLUE)

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent, size=(500,500) )

        self.panel1 = myWindow(self, size=(400,300))
        self.text = wx.StaticText(self, label="This is text.")

        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.panel1, 1, wx.ALIGN_TOP | 
                           wx.SHAPED | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=10)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.text, 0, wx.EXPAND | 
                           wx.ALIGN_TOP | wx.LEFT, border=10)
        self.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)
        self.Show()

app = wx.App(False)
panel = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: the LayoutAnchors in the demo may prove useful .... (might not also ...)

Answer (score 1):

You can't get it exactly because of the way your panel is shaped. When you make the frame too small, it will cause the panel to shrink away from the text. You can set the Frame's min size using its SetSizeHints method though, which would prevent that issue. Next you should add a spacer after the text to help keep it up against the panel. I just used a simple tuple hack for that bit.  Here's the slightly different code:

```
import wx

class myWindow(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, size):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent, size=size)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLUE)

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent, size=(500,500) )

        topPanel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel1 = myWindow(topPanel, size=(400,300))
        self.text = wx.StaticText(topPanel, label="This is text.")

        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.panel1, 8, wx.ALIGN_TOP | 
                           wx.SHAPED | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=10)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.text, 0,  
                           wx.ALIGN_TOP | wx.LEFT | wx.BOTTOM, 10)
        self.mainSizer.Add((1,1), 1, wx.EXPAND)
        topPanel.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)
        self.SetSizeHints(500, 500, 3500, 3500)
        self.Show()

app = wx.App(False)
panel = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Note that I swapped your wx.Window class for wx.Panel class since you were calling it a panel anyway. I also put a panel on the frame as that can help with the look-and-feel of the app cross-platform (and it enables tabbing between widgets).

Comment: It's a bummer that it isn't really doable, but this is an improvement. Ideally that space down bottom would disappear even at extreme window sizes, but it works in the middle. Do you know of any way to (maybe using layoutanchors) 'attach' to panels to each other?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to experiment with using the wx.SHAPED flag when adding the item to the sizer.  It is intended to cause the sizer to maintain the item's aspect ratio, although it's been so long since I've used it myself that I have no idea if it still works correctly. ;-)